# swift 4 realm filter childobjects depending on parentsname

Tags: swift, realm

I have two classes and use realm for swift 4

```
class ProjectTimeInterval : Object {
@objc dynamic var startDate = Date()
@objc dynamic var endDate : Date?
@objc dynamic var desc : String?
@objc dynamic var running : Bool = false
var parentProject = LinkingObjects(fromType: Project.self, property: "intervals")
}


class Project: Object {
@objc dynamic var name = ""
let intervals = List<ProjectTimeInterval>()
}
```

and somehow after setting the realm up and trying to fetch filtered data the app breaks

```
var intervals = realm.objects(ProjectTimeInterval.self).filter("parentProject.name MATCHES %@", project.name)
```

with this error

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid predicate', reason: 'Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate operations'

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did it myself. I need to fetch the intervals via the project so

```
var intervals = project.intervals.sorted(byKeyPath: "startDate", ascending: true)
```

like this

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the parentProject.name first if that is not set that is where you are getting that error try

```
if let parentName = parentProject.name {
      var intervals = parentName.intervals.sorted(byKeyPath: "startDate", ascending: true) 
 }
```

If this won't help then show your viewcontroller where you fetch your realm.